# is it possible to update parent table through child table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to update the column status of my Goal table if the percentage column on the Accomplishment table reach 100

```
   $accomplishment = new Accomplishment();

    $accomplishment->emp_id = Auth::user()->employees->first()->id;
    $accomplishment->goal_id = $request->goals;
    $accomplishment->date = $request->date;
    $accomplishment->accomplishment = $request->accomplishment;
    // $accomplishment->no_of_hours = $request->hours;
    $accomplishment->remarks = $request->remarks;
    $accomplishment->percentage_of_goal = $request->percentage;

    $accomplishment->save();
```

Comment: Did the part of code you showed works? I've a doubts, couse key `goals` in you request suggests it's a multiple input, but you puts it into `goal_id` (only one goal) column.

Comment: Yes, the request goals is a select with goal id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if You've added relations you can run
(if you have more than one relation to the parent, run)

```php
foreach($accomplishment->goals as $goal) {
    $goal->some_field = true;
    $goal->save();
}
```

(if you have only one parent)

```php
$accomplishment->goal->some_field = true;
$accomplishment->goal->save();
```

Inside model Accomplishment.php you should have

```php
public function goal()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Goal::class);
}
```

Or add boot method for the model and it will run each time when Accomplishment.php is creating

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($accomplishment) {
        if($accomplishment->percentage_of_goal === 100) {
            $accomplishment->goal->some_field = true;
            $accomplishment->goal->save()
        }
    });
}
```

Read more about Laravel relations here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: yes i added i relations sir, but before i update the column status in Goal table the percentage column in accomplishment should be in 100.My condition is if the percentage is 100 i will update the column status in goal table as Accomplished